Is it possible to do field comparison filter in API4?
I'm working with API4 and am unclear the syntax for a where clause (or if the following is possible). What I'd like to do is compare two custom fields in a filter for a Contact Get request. So something like this:
$contacts = \Civi\Api4\Contact::get(TRUE)
    ->addJoin('Custom_MySet AS my_set', 'LEFT', ['id', '=', 'my_set.entity_id'])
    ->addWhere('my_set.date_from', 'IS NOT EMPTY')
    ->addWhere('my_set.date_to', '<=', {my_set.date_from})
    ->addWhere('is_deleted', '=', FALSE)
    ->execute();

Note the "{my_set.date_from}" -- that's where I want to do a column comparison but am unclear the syntax required to reference another column/field rather than a static value.

Probably, in that SearchKit can do that with the fairly new 'field' option in where clauses example but Apiv4 Explorer doesn't offer that.

I think that may work -- thanks!
